# How to type formik parameters on react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I don't know how I must type the props parameter on formik component, someone can help me please?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useField, FormikProps } from 'formik';

interface InputFields {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface InputForm {
  label: string;
  props: FormikProps<InputFields>;
}

const Input = ({ label, ...props }: InputForm): JSX.Element => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{label}</label>
      <input className="text-input" {...field} {...props} />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

In the code above I get an error on in the useField, props.id and props.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
import React from "react";
import { useField, FieldHookConfig } from "formik";

interface OtherProps {
  label: string;
}

const Input = ({ label, ...props }: OtherProps & FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name}>{label}</label>
      <input className="text-input" {...field} />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

`useField` accepts either a string of a field name or an object as an argument. It is typed like this

```
export declare function useField<Val = any>(propsOrFieldName: string | FieldHookConfig<Val>): [FieldInputProps<Val>, FieldMetaProps<Val>, FieldHelperProps<Val>];
```

Here we used `FieldHookConfig<string>`.

You only really need to type the `props` of the `Input` component. TypeScript can figure out the rest on its own.